# Chef - Setting instance variable within ruby_block

Tags: chef-infra

Simple, albeit newb question regarding convergence v.s. compile time. Say I have the following library in a custom cookbook

**libraries/foo.rb**

```
class Chef::Recipe::Foo

  attr_accessor :bar

  def initialize()
    @bar = {}
  end
end
```

I then try to set the instance property `bar` within a `ruby_block` before logging an inspection

**recipes/default.rb**

```
foo = Foo.new

ruby_block "set_hash" do
  block do
    foo.bar = {'key' => 'val'}
  end
  action :run
  notifies :write, "log[inspect_hash]", :immediately
end

log "inspect_hash" do
  message foo.bar.inspect
  action :nothing
end
```

Which outputs an empty hash

```
INFO: Processing ruby_block[set_hash] action run (cookbook::default line 12)
INFO: ruby_block[set_hash] called
INFO: ruby_block[set_hash] sending write action to log[inspect_hash] (immediate)
INFO: Processing log[inspect_hash] action write (cookbook::default line 20)
INFO: {}
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ruby_block.html), during the above run, class `Foo` should have been instantiated as the recipe was compiled and the `ruby_block` evaluated as a Chef resource

> Ruby code in the ruby_block resource is evaluated with other resources
>   during convergence, whereas Ruby code outside of a ruby_block resource
>   is evaluated before other resources, as the recipe is compiled.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`run_state`](https://docs.chef.io/recipes.html#node-run-state) to store such variables spanning over multiple resources:

```rb
ruby_block "set_hash" do
  block do
    node.run_state['foo'] = {'key' => 'val'}
  end
  action :run
  notifies :write, "log[inspect_hash]", :immediately
end

log "inspect_hash" do
  lazy { message node.run_state['foo'] }
  action :nothing
end
```

Comment: I think you meant run state, not context.

Comment: Also this still needs to use the lazy helper to work.

Comment: Thanks. I was really wondering, why I didn't find any docs about it.. will update the post.

Comment: This works with the exception of the `log` resource, I was able to get it working by logging output of `node.run_state['foo'].inspect`. `.to_s` would probably work here as well. Thank you!